# Class design to contain data from an XML file

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm a student working on a lab that parses a pseudo XML file(basically coded our own parser) for data, stores the retrieved elements and data values, and displays (next lab will be adding "add,change,delete" functionality)

I was thinking about holding this read in information in some sort of multidimensional List due to it being dynamic by default. The other suggestion I've read over some other questions here at SO is to make a "parent node" class, and just store that in an array.

The problem I have is that at code time there is no way to know for sure how many child nodes a parent node will have. It could be --

```
<parent>
    <child1>data value</child1>
    <child2>data value</child2>
    ...etc
</parent>
```

or

```
<parent>
    <child1data value</child1>
</parent>
```

I can't really think how I could code a class to have an unknown amount of variables.

Comment: it appears you've been using SO as a "forum" to bounce ideas around rather than as a Q&A site (8 questions with many good answers yet 0 accepted answers). It is ok to go back and forth with comments, but eventually you should arrive upon an answer. You can use the green check to denote which answer "solved" your problem.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how to mark my questions as answered, would be the main issue with that (and also didn't realize I could...yep, I'm a noob, doh!)

Comment: that's what I figured. If you click on your name it'll take you to your profile which has all of your questions listed. Also check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), it answers a lot of questions for newcomers. Welcome to SO!

Comment: went through all my questions and marked as answered the ones I felt answered my question. Thanks for pointing that out, do I earn the "no longer a noob" badge? >.> (had to get a joke in there)

Comment: Nope, but you do get the [Scholar badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/10/scholar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a `List<List<T>>`? Or maybe a `Dictionary<string, List<T>>`, assuming your parent nodes have unique identifiers?

Comment: might need to go this route with it. As of now, parent nodes are not unique so this might fit more with what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a list of nodes or a dictionary of nodes if the nodes are unique in some way.

Answer (score 0):

.NET collections are inherently dynamic. You don't need to know in advance how many items your collection will hold. A collection of your own class "parent" would work. Each parent class itself would implement a collection of "children". You can define them to be anything you want.

Even better though would be to make your class serializable from the get go, so that when you save it to an XML file it's already in a properly formatted XML structure. Reading in that data would require deserialization and it would populate everything for you. Check [this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx).

Comment: I actually think that may be what we are doing in the long run, but won't know till I actually get the next lab.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage by your self but just think, you have parent as root and parent has **list** of child. Where is problem ? :)